# C++ vectors with structs not working?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, scanf

I was working with some files and trying to load them. I wanted to use a vector to store the final information, so I can keep it globally without needing to know how big it is. This is my code but the program doesn't finish launching:

```
std::string one = "v 100.32 12321.232 3232.6542";
struct Face {float x, y, z;};
std::vector<struct Face> obj;
char space[3];
sscanf(one.c_str(), "%s %f %f %f", space, &obj[1].x1, &obj[1].y1, &obj[1].z1);
std::cout << obj[1].x1 << std::endl;
```

Comment: You're missing `main` and `obj[whatever]` is illegal since initially, as the code is, the vector is empty.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore But doesn't sscanf add something to the vector?

Comment: No, of course not. You either need to `resize`, give a initial size with the constructor, or use `push_back`.

Comment: Nope. `operator []` is access only -- it never increases the size of the `vector`.

Comment: @BlueSpud: `map` works differently than `vector` in this regard, btw... `map::operator[]` actually creates the element if it does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default constructed `vector`s start empty, and even though the compiler lets you use `operator []`, it's undefined behavior to do so.

You can allocate some space when you create the `vector` though:

`std::vector<struct Face> obj(2); // Allow enough space to access obj[1]`

Comment: Can I just use obj.resize(5) after its declared? What I posted wasn't the entire code and the vector has no idea how much its getting until a function is called.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write to element 1 in the vector, the vector must have `size() >= 2`. In your example, `size()` is always 0.

Consider creating a temporary `Face` and then `push_back`-ing it into the `vector<Face>`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using sscanf for a good reason, but at least I think is good to point that you can use streams to load the info into the struct.

In this case, I recommend you to use istringstream class, wich lets you read values as values from a string, casting as needed. So, your code, I think I can change it to this:

```
std::string one = "v 100.32 12321.232 3232.6542";
struct Face {float x,y,z;};
std::vector<struct Face>obj;
char space[3];

// As mentioned previously, create a temporal Face variable to load the info
struct Face tmp; // The "struct" maybe can be omited, I prefer to place it.

// Create istringstream, giving it the "one" variable as buffer for read.
istringstream iss ( one );

// Replace this line...
//sscanf(one.c_str(), "%s %f %f %f",space,&obj[1].x1,&obj[1].y1,&obj[1].z1);
// With this:
iss >> space >> tmp.x >> tmp.y >> tmp.z;

// Add the temporal Face into the vector
obj.push_back ( tmp );

// As mentioned above, the first element in a vector is zero, not one
std::cout << obj[0].x1 << std::endl;
```

The istringstream class (you need to include "sstream") is useful in this cases, when you have values to load from a string.

I hope my answer can help you in any way.